# javascript calling a function on window object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and am wondering how to make the last line work. I addopted a set of api's that current use _view appended as it's namespacing convention and would rather use something like arc.view.$function_name. thx

```
var arc={};
arc.view={
  say_hello: function(){
    alert("I want to say hello");
  }
}
function say_goodbye(){
  alert("goodbye to you");
}

arc.view.say_hello(); // works
window['say_goodbye'](); // works
// possible to make this work?
window['arc.view.say_hello']();
```

Comment: because of you I am ending up my whole struggling day with a success...thanks +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
window['arc']['view']['say_hello']();
```

or

```
window.arc.view.say_hello()
```

or

```
window['arc'].view['say_hello']()
```

Either the dot syntax or the bracket syntax will work. Dot syntax is really just syntactic sugar for a bracket-based property lookup, so all of the above code snippets are identical. Use bracket syntax when the property name itself is a dynamic value, or when using the property name in dot syntax would cause a syntax error. E.g.:

```
var dynamicMethodName = someObject.getMethodName();
someOtherObject[dynamicMethodName]();
```

or

```
someOtherObject["a key string with spaces and {special characters}"]();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puEgC/1/)

```
window["arc"]["view"]["say_hello"]();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the square bracket notation you're actually asking to execute a function in window called `arc.view.say_hello`, and not a function in the object `view` (that is a property of the object `arc`). To be more explicit:

```
window["arc.view.say_hello"] = function () { alert("hi") };

window["arc.view.say_hello"](); // "hi"
```

If you want to call a function in the way you described, you have to "resolve" the objects chain. You can create an utility function for that. Something like:

```
var arc={};
arc.view={
  say_hello: function(){
    alert("I want to say hello");
  }
}
function say_goodbye(){
  alert("goodbye to you");
}

function call(id) {
    var objects = id.split(".");
    var obj = this;

    for (var i = 0, len = objects.length; i < len && obj; i++)
        obj = obj[objects[i]];

    if (typeof obj === "function")
        obj();
}

call("say_goodbye");
call("arc.view.say_hello");
```

You could also extend the utility function to use `arguments` (or you could just return the reference to the function).