# Javascript: efficiency of window object for calling user defined functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my nodejs application, I am communicating or say calling functions present in two different js file using `window.myfunction = function(){...}` way. Indeed its working perfectly. I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156474/javascript-calling-a-function-on-window-object) question as well which helped me to learn a bit better.

My question/doubt is, that is it OK to use `window` object to call user defined functions ?
(OK in terms of performance at client side, cross browser compatibility and but obvious security.)  Thanks.
(I am a sort of beginner in javascript programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what we're talking about when we talk about `Global Scope`

It's important to try and reduce the amount of code that we put in the Global Scope because it increases the chances that there will be a conflict with another library or file.

For example if you have companyA.js and demoB.js and they both contain a method called `retrieveItems` in the Global scope then there is going to be a conflict.

You, as the JS developer, need to be aware of this issue and try to take some steps to avoid these problems.

Comment: @jsonscript Sound interesting.. could you suggest some way out ? any idea ?

Comment: There's heaps. Look up the `Revealing Module Pattern` and `Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE)` and other coding patterns. Look at the way jQuery creates it's methods without exposing all it's variables...

Answer (score 0):

in the context of a browser all global functions are attached to the window object
so if you have

```
function myFunction() {
   alert("Hey!");
}
```

then

```
myFunction();
```

and

```
window.myFunction();
```

are the same calls

and yes you can define you function like `window.myFunction = function() { /*...*/ }` but it's just weird

Comment: Yes, I agree. so basically what happen my contents are being generated through server using ejs templates and if I have some function onclick event of some element, and that function is present already into some other js already loaded, in that case I used `window.myFunction` (may be my implementation is little buggy, but I have faced this issue) btw thanks for you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript programming there is a global object which is a root object that holds all the global variables. The global object depends on the runtime which you are using. Not sure of Node.js but in case javascript running in a browser, the global object is window object.
If you are creating a global variable, you are creating property on the window object.

```
    var def="Hello";
```

You can access above value using def variable or using window.def
This works on functions too.

```
    function myFunc(){
       console.log("Hello");
    }
```

So, if you see window object you will find that myFunc property is created which is holding this function.
You can execute this function using myFunc(); directly or using window.myFunc();

Global variables causes chaos, am not much in favour of global variables. Try using IIFE. Follow below link.

http://jkoder.com/avoid-polluting-global-namespace-in-javascript-iifeimmediately-invoked-function-expression/